# Calculating Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier-series

I am unable to get $2^{-|k|}$ as the Fourier coefficients of $\frac {3}{5-4\cos(x)}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ Kindly give me some clue as how to get this value $2^{-|k|}$. i am using the formula to find coefficients:

$f_k$ = $ \frac {1}{2\pi} $ $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac {3}{5-4\cos(x)}e^{-ikx} dx$ 
but since $\frac {3}{5-4\cos(x)}$ is infinitely differentiable so i am not getting the required one.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: i have edited the question after getting your comments and added more information to the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can represent

$$\frac{3}{5-4 \cos{x}} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \, e^{i n x} $$

then
$$c_n = \frac{3}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dx \, \frac{e^{i n x}}{5-4 \cos{x}} $$

We may tackle this integral using, e.g., the residue theorem.  Here, let $e^{i x}=z$; then the integral is

$$i \frac{3}{2 \pi} \oint_{|z|=1} dz \frac{z^n}{2 z^2-5 z+2} $$

Assuming $n \ge 0$, the poles of the integrand are at $z_{\pm} = (5 \pm 3)/4$.  The only pole inside the unit circle is at $z_-=1/2$.  By the residue theorem, the integral is

$$i \frac{3}{2 \pi} (i 2 \pi) \frac{(1/2)^n}{4 (1/2)-5} = 2^{-n} $$

It should be clear that the result should be the same for $n \lt 0$.  Thus, for all $n$,

> $$c_n = 2^{-|n|}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me but i have to take $e^{-ikx}$so at the end i am getting 2^k. and how the result is same for all n (i.e. why have taken absolute?)

Comment: In that case, take $z=e^{-i x}$ and you get the same integral, just take care of the signs.